# CGI code not working: Internal Server 500

Tags: python, apache2

I am newbie to Apache, and I am trying to move one web application (which is html and python scripts) from one server to another. There is the html file which is calling the python script, and I had placed the cg-bin folder in the www folder, so when I lunch the HTML which calls the python script, then it will generate 500 Internal Server Error.

Any support?

Thanks in advance for your support,

Comment: Check the error log of the Apache server for an error message and add it to the question together with your code!

Comment: first you have to check Apache log - it should show what is the problem. Apache doesn't have to run CGI - it may need to install extension and change settings (and restart). CGI is old method to generate HTML and server may preffer to run PHP or some framework instead of CGI.

Comment: MY.IP- - [23/May/2021:15:49:26 +0000] "GET /css/fonts/majalla-webfont.woff2 HTTP/1.1" 200 22669 "https://dalr.ai/css/main.css" "Mozilla/5.0 (Macintosh; Intel Mac OS X 10_15_7) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/90.0.4430.212 Safari/537.36"
MY.IP- - [23/May/2021:15:49:27 +0000] "POST /cgi-bin/SpellCheck.py 

HTTP/1.1" 500 827 "https://dalr.ai/demo1.html" "Mozilla/5.0 (Macintosh; Intel Mac OS X 10_15_7) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/90.0.4430.212 Safari/537.36"

the file demo1.html is calling SpellCheck.py

Thanks for your support,

Comment: I had tied myweb/test.py and it worked. so Apache is working with Python and I had placed the necessary files on cgi-bin